# MySQL filter first date for last user for each item

Tags: mysql

I have this problem that I've been struggling with for awhile.

I have this data:

```
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+
| id | file_id | user_id | action_datetime     |
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+
|  1 |       1 |       2 | 2014-03-13 13:39:31 |
|  2 |       1 |       2 | 2014-03-13 13:39:43 |
|  3 |       1 |       1 | 2014-03-13 13:59:34 |
|  4 |       1 |       1 | 2014-03-13 14:01:38 |
|  5 |       1 |       1 | 2014-03-13 14:03:12 |
|  6 |       2 |       2 | 2014-03-13 14:04:51 |
|  7 |       2 |       2 | 2014-03-13 14:07:37 |
|  8 |       1 |       1 | 2014-03-13 14:08:04 |
|  9 |       3 |       1 | 2014-03-13 14:08:09 |
| 10 |       3 |       1 | 2014-03-13 14:08:12 |
| 11 |       4 |       1 | 2014-03-13 14:08:14 |
| 12 |       4 |       1 | 2014-03-13 14:08:16 |
| 13 |       5 |       1 | 2014-03-13 14:08:26 |
| 14 |       1 |       1 | 2014-03-13 14:08:40 |
| 15 |       2 |       2 | 2014-03-13 14:09:13 |
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+
```

I need to select rows with first date of last user for each file, i.e rows i need are:

```
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+
| id | file_id | user_id | action_datetime     |
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+
|  3 |       1 |       1 | 2014-03-13 13:59:34 |
|  6 |       2 |       2 | 2014-03-13 14:04:51 |
|  9 |       3 |       1 | 2014-03-13 14:08:09 |
| 11 |       4 |       1 | 2014-03-13 14:08:14 |
| 13 |       5 |       1 | 2014-03-13 14:08:26 |
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+
```

I tried few things along the lines of query below, but it's no good, I know. Please help.

```
SELECT
t1.id as id,
t1.file_id as file_id,
t1.user_id as user_id,
t1.action_datetime as datetime
FROM `table_1` as t1 
WHERE t1.`id` IN (SELECT MIN(id) FROM `table_1` GROUP BY `file_id`)
```

SQL Fiddle [HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba935f/4)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your expected output, the first row should have id as 1 na as `action_datetime=2014-03-13 13:39:31` is the first date??

Comment: What would the expected result be if user_id 2 had crept in between rows 4 and 5?

Comment: Not sure i understand your question... file 1 has 2 users, i need first date of the last user. This is row id 3

Comment: @Strawberry row 5 i mean it will become 6

Comment: Hm, In that case this is a tricky problem!...

Comment: I think you should amend your data set to be more illustrative of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT t.* FROM (
  SELECT t2.`file_id`, t2.`user_id`, MIN(t2.`action_datetime`) ts_first_date FROM (
    SELECT t1.*
    FROM table_1 t1
    JOIN (
      SELECT `file_id`, MAX(`action_datetime`) as ts_last_user
      FROM table_1
      GROUP BY `file_id`
    ) tmp2
    ON tmp2.`file_id` = t1.`file_id` AND tmp2.ts_last_user = t1.action_datetime
  ) t3
  JOIN table_1 t2
  ON t3.`file_id` = t2.`file_id` AND t3.`user_id` = t2.`user_id`
  GROUP BY t2.`file_id`, t2.`user_id`
) outertable
JOIN
table_1 t
ON t.user_id = outertable.user_id AND t.file_id = outertable.file_id AND t.action_datetime = outertable.ts_first_date
ORDER BY t.file_id
```

I know its hard to understand but still it works :)

Working Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba935f/105

Inner most join is used to find the pair of file_id and user_id to get who was to last user on a file. Then you use this pair in other joins to get the first access date for this particular group.

Comment: Although this may work with the data set provided, that data set is not properly representative of the problem. Insert a '2' between all the '1's and this will return the wrong result.

Comment: @Strawberry do you mean this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eda566/1 ? I have changed user_id from 1 to 2. Seems to work.

Comment: According to the OP's comments above, it should return 6, not 3.

Comment: @Strawberry: This situation is unlikely in my case but yes, it should be row 6. Is there a way to rework the query to accommodate this? But again, it my application recurring users are highly unlikely

Answer (score -2):

Agree with *G one*’s comment, the first line in your desired output should have `user_id=2` with `action_datetime=2014-03-13 13:39:31`, otherwise it does not seem to make sense. (Or you did not phrase your problem so that we could understand it correctly.)

Do get that, you can use the approach described in the MySQL manual as [The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html):

```
SELECT
    t1.id AS id,
    t1.file_id AS file_id,
    t1.user_id AS user_id,
    t1.action_datetime AS datetime
FROM table_1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table_1 t2
  ON t1.file_id = t2.file_id
  AND t1.action_datetime > t2.action_datetime
WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba935f/62

Edit: OK, if you really want row #3 on the base of it being the “first date for the last user”, then you will have to apply this approach two times, nested into each other: First to get the IDs of the last users, and then again to get the minimum date based on the combination of file and user.

Comment: This is only half the answer. (It's also a bit 'old school', if you know what I mean! ;-) )

Comment: No, I don’t know what you mean by old school in this context; and your answer is not an answer at all btw.

Comment: @Gone: No, it gives an _error_ in any other SQL implementation than MySQL (and in MySQL as well, if it is not configured to be “tolerant” of this SQL standard violation), because you are selecting columns that are not part of the GROUPing, which is _not allowed_ (and will get you results from _random_ rows in MySQL’s tolerant mode).